# Flutter, How to add animation when redirecting screen using Get.off()?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, redirect, get

I have this line `Get.off(() => const AllergyConfigurationScreen());` which redirects to another screen. Is it possible to add animation by integrating a `PageRouteBuilder`?

`preferences_controller.dart`

```
case 0:
          // form validation
          if (!updateVeganFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            updateVeganFormKey.currentState!.save();
            return;
          }

          if (!updateDairyFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            updateDairyFormKey.currentState!.save();
            return;
          }

          Map<String, dynamic> Diet = {
            'Diet': {
              'IsVegan': isVegan.value,
              'IsDairyFree': isDairyFree.value,
            },
          };

          // Update the 'isVegan' field within the 'Diet' map
          Diet['Diet']['IsVegan'] = isVegan.value;
          Diet['Diet']['IsDairyFree'] = isDairyFree.value;

          // Create the data to update in Firestore
          Map<String, dynamic> dietData = {
            'Preferences': {
              'Allergy': {
                'IsEgg': userController.user.value.preferences['Allergy']
                    ?['IsEgg'],
                'IsNut': userController.user.value.preferences['Allergy']
                    ?['IsNut'],
              },
              'Diet': {
                'IsVegan': isVegan.value,
                'IsDairyFree': isDairyFree.value,
              },
            },
          };
          await userRepository.updateSingleField(dietData);

          // update the rx user value
          userController.user.value.preferences['IsVegan'] = isVegan.value;
          userController.user.update((user) {
            user?.preferences['Diet'] ??= {};
            user?.preferences['Diet']['IsVegan'] = isVegan.value;
          });

          userController.user.value.preferences['IsDairyFree'] =
              isDairyFree.value;
          userController.user.update((user) {
            user?.preferences['Diet'] ??= {};
            user?.preferences['Diet']['IsDairyFree'] = isDairyFree.value;
          });

          Get.off(() => const AllergyConfigurationScreen());
          break;
```

`PageRouteBuilder()`

```
PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const AllergyConfigurationScreen(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative video! I'll definitely look into other options of state management, just that currently the tutorial I'm following for my first project is using GetX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Get.off(()=>NewPage(),transition: Transition.downToUp);
```

have you tried transition property,If you find this transition type unsuitable, feel free to change it to one that better suits your needs.

Comment: Whoops... this was my bad, didn't check if there was a transition property. Thanks anyways!